# How can I start NodeJS post?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, api, mongoose

I am trying to create a sample API of restaurants using POST but after starting API and loading it into Postman it does not show results.

router.js

```
const express = require('express');
const restaurantController = require('../Controllers/restaurantData');

const router = express.Router();

router.post('/restaurantFilter',(req, res) => {
    restaurantController.getfilter
});

module.exports = router;
```

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const apiRouter = require('./Routes/router');

const port = 4005;
const app = express();

app.use(bodyparser.json());

app.use('/api', apiRouter);

mongoose.connect(
    'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/sample',
    { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }
).then(success => {
    console.log('Connected to MongoDB');

    app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log(`Server started at port ${port}`);
    });

}).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

restaurant.js (Controller)

```
const restaurants = require('../Models/restaurantData');

exports.getfilter = (req, res) => {
    const city_name = req.body.city_name;
    const cost = req.body.cost;
    restaurants.find({
        city_name: city_name,
        cost: cost
    }).then(result => {
        res.status(200).json({
            message: "Filtered Data",
            result
        })
    }).catch(error => {
        res.status(500).json({
        message: error
        })
    })
}
```

restaurantData.js (Model)

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const restaurantSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    city_name:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    city: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    area: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    locality:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    thumb: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    cost:{
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    address:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    mealtype:{
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    name:{
        type: String,
            required: true
        },    
    cuisine:{
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    type:{
        type: Array,
        required: true
    },
    Cuisine:{
        type: Array,
        required: true
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('restaurantData', restaurantSchema, 'restaurantData');
```

I think mostly it is the router problem but trying to know where? So, share any ideas. Thank You.

Comment: In your `router.post()`, try to change the `restaurantController.getfilter` to `res.send(restaurantController.getfilter)`

Comment: @hisam - That is not correct.   `restaurantController.getfilter` is a function and it needs to be called and passed `req` and `res`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This request handler:

```
router.post('/restaurantFilter',(req, res) => {
    restaurantController.getfilter
});
```

Does not actually call the `getfilter` function so nothing is ever sent from the POST request.  You can fix that by either doing this:

```
router.post('/restaurantFilter', restaurantController.getfilter);
```

or this:

```
router.post('/restaurantFilter',(req, res) => {
    restaurantController.getfilter(req, res);
});
```

Then, it looks like you also have to property export and import that `getfilter()` function.  You appear to export it just fine in `restaurant.js`:

```
exports.getfilter = (req, res) => { ... });
```

But, you don't seem to be importing the controller properly as you're doing this:

```
const restaurantController = require('../Controllers/restaurantData');
```

When it looks like you should be doing this:

```
const restaurantController = require('../Controllers/restaurant.js');
```

so that you're assigning the controller the object that actually has the `getfilter` method on it.